# Haskell llvm-general JIT: calling a C function on the fly. Stephen Diehl's tutorial

Tags: haskell, llvm

I am following [Stephen Diehl's excellent LLVM Haskell tutorial](http://www.stephendiehl.com/llvm/) on a Linux Mint box (Linux Mint 17 Qiana, GHC 7.8.4, llvm 3.4).

I cloned the project's github repo and I was able to build each chapter's example by using the included `Makefile`.

In chapter 4 the tutorial presents us a JIT compiler:

```
import qualified LLVM.General.ExecutionEngine as EE

jit :: Context -> (EE.MCJIT -> IO a) -> IO a
jit c = EE.withMCJIT c optlevel model ptrelim fastins
  where
    optlevel = Just 2  -- optimization level
    model    = Nothing -- code model ( Default )
    ptrelim  = Nothing -- frame pointer elimination
    fastins  = Nothing -- fast instruction selection

runJIT :: AST.Module -> IO (Either String ())
runJIT mod = do
    ...
    jit context $ \executionEngine ->
        ...
        EE.withModuleInEngine executionEngine m $ \ee -> do
          mainfn <- EE.getFunction ee (AST.Name "main")
          case mainfn of
            Just fn -> do
              res <- run fn
              putStrLn $ "Evaluated to: " ++ show res
            Nothing -> return ()
```

Then the tutorial extends the language by writing C code to implement operations.

```
/* cbits
$ gcc -fPIC -shared cbits.c -o cbits.so
$ clang -fPIC -shared cbits.c -o cbits.so
*/

#include "stdio.h"

// putchard - putchar that takes a double and returns 0.
double putchard(double X) {
  putchar((char)X);
  fflush(stdout);
  return 0;
}
```

The makefile builds the project by running:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared src/chapter4/cbits.c -o src/chapter4/cbits.so
ghc -no-user-package-db -package-db .cabal-sandbox/*-packages.conf.d src/chapter4/cbits.so --make src/chapter4/*.hs -o chapter4
```

But when I try to call `putchard()` I get an error:

```
LLVM ERROR: Program used external function 'putchard' which could not be resolved!
```

Am I missing something here?

I've seen people having a similar issue with the original C++ version of the tutorial. They usually solve it by adding a flag to gcc build command (`-rdynamic`) which is supposed to make the linker add all symbols, no only used ones, to the dynamic symbol table. I suspect ghc is stripping `putchard()` from the executable file.

When I follow the exact same steps on OS X I everything works fine and I can call `putchard()` without a problem.

What's happening?

I just tried running the project on Centos 7 and it worked. There must be something wrong with my Mint machine.

Comment: Does adding ``-optl -rdynamic`` to the invocation of ghc fix the problem? Can you run ``nm chapter4 | grep putchard`` and paste the resulting output in the question?

Comment: Stephen, I had tried adding `-optl -rdynamic` but it didnt' work. Unfortunately the output to `nm chapter4 | grep putchard` is null. It seems like ghc is ignoring `cbits.so`. On OS X the executable won't even run if it doesn't find `cbits.so`. On linux it does not make a difference. Maybe there's a way to link with ld instead of ghc? What was your setup when writing the tutorial?

Comment: I've tested the code on both Ubuntu and Arch Linux. People have reported running it on every major operating system though. Perhaps there was a linker bug upstream in GHC that is a bit overzealous at stripping symbols that don't appear in the Haskell source. Have you tried it on either 7.6 or 7.10?

Comment: I tried on latest Ubuntu  (14.10) and it doesn't work there as well. So far what I tested was: CentOS 7 (works), Mint 17 (doesn't work), Ubuntu 14.10 (doesn't work), OS 10.10 (works).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps GHC is being a bit overzealous during linking and stripping out the symbol? Can you manually add a reference using the FFI in `Main.hs` and then recompile.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

import Foreign.C.Types

foreign import ccall safe "putchard" putchard
    :: CDouble -> CDouble
```

Comment: I'll be damned! This solution *did* work (manually adding a reference in `Main.hs`.) Before trying that I tried using GHC 7.6 and GHC 7.8. I tried a hack to use `ld.gold` instead of `ld.ld`, but none of that worked.